# paste clipboard text plus string with .inputrc

Tags: bash, clipboard, readline, line-editor, inputrc

I've got in my .inputrc something like

```
"\C-v": "script.sh "
```

I use a link from my clipboard as a parameter for the script, so I type ctrl-v and then paste the link, and then hit enter.

So I've seen that you can use "paste-from-clipboard" to actually paste something.

Is there a way to get this done alltogether by .inputrc? Something like

```
"\C-v": "script.sh ", paste-from-clipboard, "\n"
```

Comment: I dont know how to do this in bash, but you can do this with a keybinding in `xterm`, and perhaps some derived tty emulators.